# Trouble with checking and condensing lists of conditions in strings

Tags: python, list, if-statement, comparison-operators

I've been making a sort of artificial intelligence (it's more like a long list of question - answer situations) and I've been looking to step up the complexity, but I know there's a way to shorten the amount of typing I have to do and I can't quite find it. Anyways, here's the long version of me asking for input, then checking the type of input (for example it's a question):

```
a = input()
if "what" in a:
    a_type = question
if "where" in a:
    a_type = question
if "when" in a:
    a_type = question
if "why" in a:
    a_type = question
if "who" in a:
    a_type = question
```

and so on, then I would check for subject, mood, expression, etc...
If anybody knows **how to condense all 5 of those statements** that'd be great, thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) to test words from a sequence against `a`:

```
question_words = ['what', 'when', 'where', 'why', 'who']
if any(word in a for word in question_words):
    a_type = question
```

`any()` iterates over the generator expression and returns `True` as soon as one of the `word in a` tests is true, or `False` when the generator expression is exhausted.